# BitNami LAMP stack on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, lamp

I just installed BitNami LAMP stack on ubuntu. When I visit localhost/127.0.0.1 Apache returns "403 Forbidden. You don't have permission to access / on this server." I try repointing Apache's home directory to another folder (same hard drive, same partition) that's set to 777 recursively. Still getting 403. And then I change the ownership of the directory to under my username and daemon group from root/root. Same error. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Anything set recursively to 777 is wrong. Full stop. Period. The end.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following command:

```
sudo ./ctl.sh start apache
```

You will be asked to enter the password - it will then start.